# Need help with Shadows

Tags: xna, shadow-mapping

I have started to develop [Project Vanquish](https://projectvanquish.wordpress.com),
(an XNA, deferred rendering engine) but my shadows are not working correctly.  I have been working for a week on it and can't figure out what is going wrong.  I will be putting a 200 point bounty on this question, so if anyone solves the problem, I'll reward them.  Source code is over at Codeplex too, grab the latest changeset.

I have the ShadowMap phase working, but the Shadow Occlusion stage doesn't appear to be working.  At certain points, the debug RenderTarget will show the scene, but the scene is wrong.  It shows black across the top with the outline of the model and nothing else.

[image]

```
protected void DrawShadowOcclusion(GraphicsDevice device, ICamera camera, RenderTarget2D depthTexture)
{
    // Set the device to render the shadow occlusion texture
    device.SetRenderTarget(shadowOcclusion);

    Matrix cameraTransform;
    camera.GetWorldMatrix(out cameraTransform);

    // Determine which split a pixel belongs too
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SPLITS; i++)
    {
        lightClipPlanes[i].X = -splitDepths[i];
        lightClipPlanes[i].Y = -splitDepths[i + 1];
        lightCameras[i].GetViewProjectionMatrix(out lightViewProjectionMatrices[i]);
    }

    // Setup the shadow effect
    shadowEffect.CurrentTechnique = shadowOcclusionTechniques[(int)filteringType];
    shadowEffect.Parameters["g_matInvView"].SetValue(cameraTransform);
    shadowEffect.Parameters["g_matLightViewProj"].SetValue(lightViewProjectionMatrices);
    shadowEffect.Parameters["g_vFrustumCornersVS"].SetValue(farFrustumCornerVS);
    shadowEffect.Parameters["g_vClipPlanes"].SetValue(lightClipPlanes);
    shadowEffect.Parameters["ShadowMap"].SetValue(shadowMap);
    shadowEffect.Parameters["DepthTexture"].SetValue(depthTexture);
    shadowEffect.Parameters["g_vOcclusionTextureSize"].SetValue(new Vector2(shadowOcclusion.Width, shadowOcclusion.Height));
    shadowEffect.Parameters["g_vShadowMapSize"].SetValue(new Vector2(shadowMap.Width, shadowMap.Height));
    shadowEffect.Parameters["g_bShowSplitColors"].SetValue(false);

    // Begin the effect
    shadowEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();

    // Draw the FullscreenQuad
    fullscreenQuad.Draw();
}
```

Shader code:

```
//========================================================================
//
//  DeferredShadowMaps
//
//      by MJP  (mpettineo@gmail.com)
//      12/14/08      
//
//========================================================================
//
//  File:       ShadowMap.fx
//
//  Desc:       Contains shaders used for generating and applying deferred
//              shadow maps.  
//
//========================================================================

float4x4    g_matWorld;
float4x4    g_matWorldIT;
float4x4    g_matViewProj;
float4x4    g_matInvView;
float       g_fFarClip;
static const int NUM_SPLITS = 4;
float4x4    g_matLightViewProj [NUM_SPLITS];
float2      g_vClipPlanes[NUM_SPLITS];
float2      g_vShadowMapSize;
float2      g_vOcclusionTextureSize;
float3      g_vFrustumCornersVS [4];
bool        g_bShowSplitColors = false;
static const float BIAS = 0.006f;

texture DepthTexture;
sampler2D DepthTextureSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <DepthTexture>;
    MinFilter = point;
    MagFilter = point;
    MipFilter = none;
};

texture ShadowMap;
sampler2D ShadowMapSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <ShadowMap>;
    MinFilter = point; 
    MagFilter = point; 
    MipFilter = none; 
};

// Vertex shader for outputting light-space depth to the shadow map
void GenerateShadowMapVS(in float4 in_vPositionOS   : POSITION,
                         out float4 out_vPositionCS : POSITION,
                         out float2 out_vDepthCS    : TEXCOORD0)
{
    // Figure out the position of the vertex in view space and clip space
    float4x4 matWorldViewProj = mul(g_matWorld, g_matViewProj);
    out_vPositionCS = mul(in_vPositionOS, matWorldViewProj);
    out_vDepthCS = out_vPositionCS.zw;
}

// Pixel shader for outputting light-space depth to the shadow map
float4 GenerateShadowMapPS(in float2 in_vDepthCS : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    // Negate and divide by distance to far clip (so that depth is in range [0,1])
    float fDepth = in_vDepthCS.x / in_vDepthCS.y;           
        
    return float4(fDepth, 1, 1, 1); 
}

// Vertex shader for rendering the full-screen quad used for calculating
// the shadow occlusion factor.
void ShadowTermVS (in float3 in_vPositionOS             : POSITION,
                   in float3 in_vTexCoordAndCornerIndex : TEXCOORD0,        
                   out float4 out_vPositionCS           : POSITION,
                   out float2 out_vTexCoord             : TEXCOORD0,
                   out float3 out_vFrustumCornerVS      : TEXCOORD1)
{
    // Offset the position by half a pixel to correctly align texels to pixels
    out_vPositionCS.x = in_vPositionOS.x - (1.0f / g_vOcclusionTextureSize.x);
    out_vPositionCS.y = in_vPositionOS.y + (1.0f / g_vOcclusionTextureSize.y);
    out_vPositionCS.z = in_vPositionOS.z;
    out_vPositionCS.w = 1.0f;
    
    // Pass along the texture coordiante and the position of the frustum corner
    out_vTexCoord = in_vTexCoordAndCornerIndex.xy;
    out_vFrustumCornerVS = g_vFrustumCornersVS[in_vTexCoordAndCornerIndex.z];
}   

// Calculates the shadow occlusion using bilinear PCF
float CalcShadowTermPCF(float fLightDepth, float2 vShadowTexCoord)
{
    float fShadowTerm = 0.0f;

    // transform to texel space
    float2 vShadowMapCoord = g_vShadowMapSize * vShadowTexCoord;
    
    // Determine the lerp amounts           
    float2 vLerps = frac(vShadowMapCoord);

    // Read in the 4 samples, doing a depth check for each
    float fSamples[4];  
    fSamples[0] = (tex2D(ShadowMapSampler, vShadowTexCoord).x + BIAS < fLightDepth) ? 0.0f: 1.0f;  
    fSamples[1] = (tex2D(ShadowMapSampler, vShadowTexCoord + float2(1.0/g_vShadowMapSize.x, 0)).x + BIAS < fLightDepth) ? 0.0f: 1.0f;  
    fSamples[2] = (tex2D(ShadowMapSampler, vShadowTexCoord + float2(0, 1.0/g_vShadowMapSize.y)).x + BIAS < fLightDepth) ? 0.0f: 1.0f;  
    fSamples[3] = (tex2D(ShadowMapSampler, vShadowTexCoord + float2(1.0/g_vShadowMapSize.x, 1.0/g_vShadowMapSize.y)).x + BIAS < fLightDepth) ? 0.0f: 1.0f;  
    
    // lerp between the shadow values to calculate our light amount
    fShadowTerm = lerp(lerp(fSamples[0], fSamples[1], vLerps.x), lerp( fSamples[2], fSamples[3], vLerps.x), vLerps.y);                            
                                
    return fShadowTerm;                              
}

// Calculates the shadow term using PCF soft-shadowing
float CalcShadowTermSoftPCF(float fLightDepth, float2 vShadowTexCoord, int iSqrtSamples)
{
    float fShadowTerm = 0.0f;  
        
    float fRadius = (iSqrtSamples - 1.0f) / 2;
    float fWeightAccum = 0.0f;
    
    for (float y = -fRadius; y <= fRadius; y++)
    {
        for (float x = -fRadius; x <= fRadius; x++)
        {
            float2 vOffset = 0;
            vOffset = float2(x, y);             
            vOffset /= g_vShadowMapSize;
            float2 vSamplePoint = vShadowTexCoord + vOffset;            
            float fDepth = tex2D(ShadowMapSampler, vSamplePoint).x;
            float fSample = (fLightDepth <= fDepth + BIAS);
            
            // Edge tap smoothing
            float xWeight = 1;
            float yWeight = 1;
            
            if (x == -fRadius)
                xWeight = 1 - frac(vShadowTexCoord.x * g_vShadowMapSize.x);
            else if (x == fRadius)
                xWeight = frac(vShadowTexCoord.x * g_vShadowMapSize.x);
                
            if (y == -fRadius)
                yWeight = 1 - frac(vShadowTexCoord.y * g_vShadowMapSize.y);
            else if (y == fRadius)
                yWeight = frac(vShadowTexCoord.y * g_vShadowMapSize.y);
                
            fShadowTerm += fSample * xWeight * yWeight;
            fWeightAccum = xWeight * yWeight;
        }                                           
    }       
    
    fShadowTerm /= (iSqrtSamples * iSqrtSamples);
    fShadowTerm *= 1.55f;   
    
    return fShadowTerm;
}

// Pixel shader for computing the shadow occlusion factor
float4 ShadowTermPS(in float2 in_vTexCoord          : TEXCOORD0,
                    in float3 in_vFrustumCornerVS   : TEXCOORD1,
                    uniform int iFilterSize)    : COLOR0
{
    // Reconstruct view-space position from the depth buffer
    float fPixelDepth = tex2D(DepthTextureSampler, in_vTexCoord).r;
    float4 vPositionVS = float4(fPixelDepth * in_vFrustumCornerVS, 1.0f);   
    
    // Figure out which split this pixel belongs to, based on view-space depth.
    float4x4 matLightViewProj = g_matLightViewProj[0];
    float fOffset = 0;
    
    float3 vSplitColors [4];
    vSplitColors[0] = float3(1, 0, 0);
    vSplitColors[1] = float3(0, 1, 0);
    vSplitColors[2] = float3(0, 0, 1);
    vSplitColors[3] = float3(1, 1, 0);
    float3 vColor = vSplitColors[0];
    int iCurrentSplit = 0;
        
    // Unrolling the loop allows for a performance boost on the 360
#ifdef XBOX 
    [unroll(NUM_SPLITS - 1)]
#endif  
    for (int i = 1; i < NUM_SPLITS; i++)
    {
#ifdef XBOX     
        [flatten]
#endif      
        if (vPositionVS.z <= g_vClipPlanes[i].x && vPositionVS.z > g_vClipPlanes[i].y)
        {
            matLightViewProj = g_matLightViewProj[i];
            fOffset = i / (float)NUM_SPLITS;
            vColor = vSplitColors[i];
            iCurrentSplit = i;
        }
    }       
    
    // If we're not showing the split colors, set it back to 1 to remove the coloring
    if (!g_bShowSplitColors)
        vColor = 1;     
    
    // Determine the depth of the pixel with respect to the light
    float4x4 matViewToLightViewProj = mul(g_matInvView, matLightViewProj);
    float4 vPositionLightCS = mul(vPositionVS, matViewToLightViewProj);
    
    float fLightDepth = vPositionLightCS.z / vPositionLightCS.w;    
    
    // Transform from light space to shadow map texture space.
    float2 vShadowTexCoord = 0.5 * vPositionLightCS.xy / vPositionLightCS.w + float2(0.5f, 0.5f);
    vShadowTexCoord.x = vShadowTexCoord.x / NUM_SPLITS + fOffset;
    vShadowTexCoord.y = 1.0f - vShadowTexCoord.y;
        
    // Offset the coordinate by half a texel so we sample it correctly
    vShadowTexCoord += (0.5f / g_vShadowMapSize);
    
    // Get the shadow occlusion factor and output it
    float fShadowTerm = 0;
    if (iFilterSize == 2)
        fShadowTerm = CalcShadowTermPCF(fLightDepth, vShadowTexCoord);
    else
        fShadowTerm = CalcShadowTermSoftPCF(fLightDepth, vShadowTexCoord, iFilterSize);

    return float4(fShadowTerm * vColor, 1);
}

technique GenerateShadowMap
{
    pass p0
    {
        ZWriteEnable = true;
        ZEnable = true;     
        AlphaBlendEnable = false;
        FillMode = Solid;
        CullMode = CCW;
        
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 GenerateShadowMapVS();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 GenerateShadowMapPS();
    }
}

technique CreateShadowTerm2x2PCF
{
    pass p0
    {
        ZWriteEnable = false;
        ZEnable = false;
        AlphaBlendEnable = false;
        CullMode = NONE;

        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 ShadowTermVS();
        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 ShadowTermPS(2);   
    }
}

technique CreateShadowTerm3x3PCF
{
    pass p0
    {
        ZWriteEnable = false;
        ZEnable = false;
        AlphaBlendEnable = false;
        CullMode = NONE;

        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 ShadowTermVS();
        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 ShadowTermPS(3);   
    }
}

technique CreateShadowTerm5x5PCF
{
    pass p0
    {
        ZWriteEnable = false;
        ZEnable = false;
        AlphaBlendEnable = false;
        CullMode = NONE;

        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 ShadowTermVS();
        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 ShadowTermPS(5);   
    }
}

technique CreateShadowTerm7x7PCF
{
    pass p0
    {
        ZWriteEnable = false;
        ZEnable = false;
        AlphaBlendEnable = false;
        CullMode = NONE;

        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 ShadowTermVS();
        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 ShadowTermPS(7);   
    }
}
```

By changing the `g_matInvView` line to :

```
shadowEffect.Parameters["g_matInvView"].SetValue(Matrix.Invert(cameraTransform));
```

I get:

[image: New Shadow Error]

Comment: Can't help you if you don't go into detail explaining the problem...

Comment: It looks like you are using deferred rendering, what source have you followed?

Comment: Ah, I'm afraid I haven't added shadow mapping myself yet, so I can't give you much insights there yet. Have you come around to narrowing down your problem more?

Comment: Well, show us that part of the code, some test cases and more screenshots!

Comment: Please show the shader code too and explain what techniques you are using (plain SM, filtering, PSM, ...)

Comment: @Valmond: Added the shader code

Comment: "At certain points, the debug RenderTarget will show the scene, but the scene is wrong" Is it Always wrong? Is the final render Sometimes OK? PS. I'd start by skipping all filtering stuff (PCF & the lerp stuff) to clear the code a bit. PPS. Are you sure the depth map is correct (the white-blue debug target)?

Comment: Another question, what is the second debug render target showing? Normals? If so I'd skip that to at the moment and get the shadow map(s) up and running first. Oh yeah almost forgot, good luck ;-)

Comment: @Valmond: thanks for your input.  The rendering appears to be fine.  As the last scene (shadow occlusion) is a fullscreen quad render, so I don't see that causing a problem.  It is a very frustrating issue, but will take on board your steps and try again :)

Comment: OK so its deferred shading, the black-white image seems to say that you don't even have the colour but maybe it is just, as you say, a 'debug' output. What is wrong with the lower image (the big bottom one, it seems there are shadows)? One thing that helped me (doing PSSM) was to render a debug rendertarget from the lights view (so I 'see' what the light 'sees').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the `QuadRenderer` that I was using.  The reason for the "lines" across the line image is because is was displaying the 4 shadow occlusions rather than displaying one fullscreen quad.  I created a new class in order to cater for this and changed the `QuadRenderer` for this new class.

```
public class FullScreenQuad
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A struct that represents a single vertex in the
    /// vertex buffer.
    /// </summary>
    private struct QuadVertex
        : IVertexType
    {
        public Vector3 position;
        public Vector3 texCoordAndCornerIndex;
        public readonly static VertexDeclaration VertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration(
                new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),
                new VertexElement(12, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0)
            );

        VertexDeclaration IVertexType.VertexDeclaration
        {
            get { return VertexDeclaration; }
        }
    }

    VertexBuffer vertexBuffer;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the quad's vertex buffer
    /// </summary>
    public VertexBuffer VertexBuffer
    {
        get { return vertexBuffer; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an instance of FullScreenQuad
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="graphicsDevice">The GraphicsDevice to use for creating resources</param>
    public FullScreenQuad(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
    {
        CreateFullScreenQuad(graphicsDevice);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Draws the full screen quad
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="graphicsDevice">The GraphicsDevice to use for rendering</param>
    public void Draw(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
    {
        // Set the vertex buffer and declaration
        graphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);

        // Draw primitives
        graphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, 0, 2);

        graphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the VertexBuffer for the quad
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="graphicsDevice">The GraphicsDevice to use</param>
    private void CreateFullScreenQuad(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
    {
        // Create a vertex buffer for the quad, and fill it in
        vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(graphicsDevice, typeof(QuadVertex), QuadVertex.VertexDeclaration.VertexStride * 4, BufferUsage.None);
        QuadVertex[] vbData = new QuadVertex[4];

        // Upper right
        vbData[0].position = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        vbData[0].texCoordAndCornerIndex = new Vector3(1, 0, 1);

        // Lower right
        vbData[1].position = new Vector3(1, -1, 1);
        vbData[1].texCoordAndCornerIndex = new Vector3(1, 1, 2);

        // Upper left
        vbData[2].position = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
        vbData[2].texCoordAndCornerIndex = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        // Lower left
        vbData[3].position = new Vector3(-1, -1, 1);
        vbData[3].texCoordAndCornerIndex = new Vector3(0, 1, 3);

        vertexBuffer.SetData(vbData);
    }
}
```